# how to generate pdf in arabic from oracle report builder 6i?

Tags: oracle, pdf, arabic, oraclereports

dear all I need to create an oracle report (v 6i) in which I have display one paragraph in English and another one paragraph in Arabic. The text can be static(hardcoded) or can be dynamic (can be selected from the table). I have copied an Arabic paragraph from ms word & pasted it in a table through toad. When I see the inserted text through toad/SQL plus is displays it in Arabic, but when I am displaying it through Oracle reports it displays some junk characters.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Paper layout editor; in there, set Arabic text **font** to the one that supports Arabic alphabet. If it is, for example, Arial (by default), it can't show Arabic letters so you'll get junk as Reports will try to perform font substitution (and fail). I don't know which fonts support Arabic language, I don't use it.

Also, note that Reports 6i is a client-server version which means that you'll have to install that font on all computers which will be using that report (otherwise all users will see junk as well).

Comment: ARIAL fonts support Arabic language but it doesn't work correctly while generating pdf,
it still shows junk

Comment: PDF reader displays it clearly but when we use the report builder to generate desformat as PDF it shows the Arabic characters as junk.